# Finding and fixing expected location of libraries

Tags: nvidia, libraries

glxgears ran by a normal user cannot find `libGL.so.1`:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/glxgears 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffce3176000)
    libGL.so.1 => not found
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd2c5381000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fd2c5047000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd2c4c7c000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000563b86149000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fd2c4a5a000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd2c4856000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fd2c4651000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fd2c444b000)
```

But sudo can, in a installation dir for AMD drivers (the system has GPUS from both makers):

```
$ sudo ldd /usr/bin/glxgears 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcb6b8c000)
    libGL.so.1 => /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f89792ec000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8978fe3000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f8978ca9000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f89788de000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f89786c1000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f89784af000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f89782ab000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f89780a5000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f8977ea3000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f8977c89000)
    libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f8977a86000)
    libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f8977883000)
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f897767d000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f897745b000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f8977255000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f8977040000)
    libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f8976e3d000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f8976c36000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055ac620c0000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8976a31000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f897682d000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f8976626000)
```

And it is also able to find a bunch more libraries.

`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` returns empty for both normal user and root. The point of this question is not finding a workaround using LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

1. How can I see where a certain program is actually looking for the libraries? When it's missing, `ldd` doesn't say where is it missing *from*.

A: Use -v:

```
ldd -v /usr/bin/glxgears
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc90b70000)
        libGL.so.1 => /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f2bf1faf000)
```

2. Where is the list of locations to look for a certain library? Sudo was able to find it, so where does the system keep that information?
3. How can I change the setting so that the system goes looking for `libGL.so.1` within the Nvidia installed files and not the amdgpu-pro installation.

Comment: Did you trying using LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: The order in which dynamic library dependencies are resolved is detailed in `man ld.so` - AFAIK it should be the same for all users aside from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (but that would need to be set via `sudoers` in order to explain why it's only resolved under `sudo`). I wonder if it's just accessibility - what is the output of `sudo namei -l /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1` ?

Comment: If User can't see the file, but `root` can, check permissions for the file and intervening directories. I wrote a script to make this easier. https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?"

Comment: I know that along the path to libGL.so.1 in /opt there is a restriction for normal users to read the file. Modifying permissions to this file is not the point of this question.

Comment: I didn't try using LD_LIBRARY_PATH (which is empty btw). I know where I can find missing libraries, What I don't know is how to find out where a certain program is looking for them.